# Bootstrap UI Behavior on vertical scroll

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to find examples or keyword that I can use to Google how to create Bootstrap sites with scroll options as show in site below:

```
https://stockflare.com/landing
```

Or how when scrolling down the image stays static while in view:

```
http://welfordmedia.co.uk/
```

Any pointers would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to [**codrops**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/02/fixed-background-scrolling-layout/) where you can download working sample.
This is the same as your first example.

The second example would use **position: fixed;** in your css code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's true "scrolling" involved in the first page... It appears the page just captures 'scroll' events, determines if the event was for an up or down scroll, then runs a JS/css animation that slides one div away (absolute position, gradually decrease top: to 0 - height)... This simulates scrolling and exposes the new 'page'.